# Getting .NET to understand Oracle Objects in a returned REF_CURSOR

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, plsql

I am having an issue where I am trying to return a "nested object" to a cSharp program but .net is having difficulty understanding the data that is gettting returned.

Here is what I have in Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST.OBJ_BASE_EVENT FORCE AS OBJECT
(
   prop1          number(10),
   prop2          number(5),
   prop3          varchar2(100)
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST.OBJ_EXTENDED_EVENT FORCE AS OBJECT
(
   base_event           TEST.OBJ_BASE_EVENT
   extended_prop1       number(15),
   extended_prop2       number(15)
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE COM_API.TAB_EXTENDED_EVENT is table of TEST."OBJ_EXTENDED_EVENT"
```

This is some code from the Oracle Proc:

```
 PROCEDURE Get_vents(xTbl OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS  

 cursor events is
select test.OBJ_EXTENDED_EVENT(test.OBJ_BASE_EVENT(prop1,prop2,prop3),
    extended_prop1, extended_prop2)
from test.test_table;


  event_tab     test.extended_event;

  BEGIN

  OPEN events;
  FETCH events BULK COLLECT
     INTO event_tab;
  CLOSE events;

  OPEN xTBL FOR
     SELECT *
       FROM TABLE(team_event_tab);

  END;
```

I can run this from pl/sql and see the results.  I will get the ref_cursor and the results are correct.
The columns do come back as:

```
 obj_base_event.prop1
 obj_base_event.prop2
 obj_base_event.prop3
 extended_prop1     
 extended_prop2
```

When I run my cSharp code.   I get the following error.

"OCI-22303: type TEST.OBJ_BASE_EVENT not found".

It seems like it sees the data but doesn't know how to handle an object being part of the ref_cursor.  Is there any way to to make .net understnad this return or a way on oracle to flatten it out so it doesn't seem to have the base object?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your Oracle `PROCEDURE` declaration look like? In C#/Oracle I've had the best luck returning data sets when the proc's signature is something like `PROCEDURE my_proc(retValue OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)`, regardless of the output type.

Comment: Is there a reason that your PL/SQL code is structured like this?  It generally makes little sense to pull a bunch of data from a table into a PL/SQL collection just to pass that collection back to the SQL engine to create a cursor.  Is there a reason that you don't just return a cursor that represents a query against `test_table` without any of the objects or collections?  If you are doing extensive manipulation of the collection between populating it and returning the cursor, could you use a pipelined table function instead?

Comment: What version of ODP.NET are you running?

Comment: Oracle has published a library to handle all of this for you.  Are you even using that library?

Comment: I am using ODP.NET 2.112.1.0.  The reason that I am using even objects,  is to maintain naming consistency across various different procs that all return similar but slightly.  I could certainly ditch the objects and just return a straight select back to .NET but wanted to see if there was something easy I am missing here.

Comment: @Ramhound - what's the name of the library, and where can it be obtained?  Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis -  The library is ODP.NET ...... don't use objects.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have a solution.

Instead of nesting the object, declare the child object using the UNDER keyword.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST.OBJ_EXTENDED_EVENT UNDER TEST.OBJ_BASE_EVENT
 (
      extended_prop1       number(15),
      extended_prop2       number(15)
 )
```

Now in the select statement you don’t have to put a custom type within a custom type, you just use the child custom type which contains all the parent attributes.